Wednesday Fasting For Ganesh Ji Questions?
Q1.) do I need to take sankalp in Fasting? (Do i need to take sankalp daily? If I planing to do fast for lifetime)
Q2.) Can I do Mansopchar Pooja of Ganesh Ji?
Q3.) Can I chant/Read Ganesh Gaytri Mantra or Ganapati Atharvasirsa on Wednesday?
Q4.) is it necessary to do pooja or offering navediyum? Or can I do Mansopchar Pooja instead? (I will do pooja or offer navediyum if it accessible to me)
Q5.) can I eat food after evening/night only 1 time a day?
Thanks in Advance ♥️
